# Open normal subgroups of Galois

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

Let $K$ be a number field, $v$ a finite place of $K$. Let $K'$ be the maximal extension of $K$ unramified at $v$.

For instance, for $K = \mathbf{Q}$ and $v = p$ a prime, $K' = \mathbf{Q}(\{\zeta_{n}, p\nmid n\})$, $\zeta_n$ primitive $n$-th roots of unity.

> Let $\overline{K}$ an algebraic closure of $K$. Is $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K')$ an open normal subgroup of $\text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$?

Answer (score 2):

For profinite groups $G$, open subgroups $H$ always have finite index, because the map $G \to G/H$ is continuous, $G/H$ has the discrete topology, and $G$ is compact. In your question, this index $[K' :K]$ is infinite, so the answer is no.

Comment: Is it clear that $[K' : K]$ is always infinite? It certainly "often" is, but is this provably true for all $K$ and $v$?

Comment: Good question, I had only given it cursory thought. Can't one just add $n$-th roots of unity for $v(n) = 0$, as in the $\mathbb{Q}$-case?

Comment: Then you get an extension ramified at all primes of $K$ dividing $n$ (and there may be more than one).

Comment: I am missing something obvious, I'm afraid. Isn't this extension still unramified at $v$, which is what we care about?

Comment: Oops, I had misread the question! I was thinking of the maximal extension ramified **only** at $v$ in which case the question of whether or not $[K' : K]$ is finite is much more subtle.

Comment: I posted my mistake as a follow-up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2693945/extensions-of-number-fields-ramified-at-a-single-place