# Extensions of number fields ramified at few places

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field and $S$ a finite set of places of $K$. Then there is a maximal algebraic extension $K^S / K$ unramified outside $S$.

> How large do we have to take $S$ to be in order that $K^S / K$ is infinite?

For $K = \mathbf{Q}$ it's necessary and sufficient that $S$ contain at least one finite place. This is not a necessary condition for every $K$, since the Golod--Shafarevich theorem shows that there are fields such that $K^S$ is infinite when $S$ is the empty set; but is it sufficient? That is:

> Does there exist a field $K$ and a finite place $v$ such that $K^{\{v\}} / K$ is finite?

There certainly exist examples such that $K^{\{v\}} / K$ contains no solvable extension of $K$, e.g. $K = \mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, $v$ the prime $1 + 2\sqrt{3}$ of norm 11.

Comment: Interesting question, and rather out of my experience. Do you have a $K$ that requires more than one place?

Comment: Is there an example of a $K$ and finite place $\mathfrak{p}$ such that the ray class fields of modulus $\mathfrak{p}^k$ stabilize eventually? In particular, can $K^S/K$ be infinite but $(K^S)^{ab}/K$ finite when $S$ contains at least one finite prime?

Comment: @BrandonCarter Sure, this can happen: take $K$ real quadratic and any prime $p = \mathfrak{p} \mathfrak{p}^\sigma$ split in $K$. Then the maximal abelian extension unramified outside $\mathfrak{p}$ is finite.

Comment: (I don't know if $K^S$ is finite in this case.)

Comment: This question is surely open. But one heuristic is that you should only expect a (general) positive answer under conditions which guarantee that the largest abelian quotient is infinite. Otherwise, it can (and sometimes does) happen that the largest abelian extension is trivial. For $K^S$ then to be infinite, there (at the very least) needs to exist an extension $L/K$ unramified outside $S$ whose Galois group $G$ is simple and non-abelian. Heuristics concerning the existence of such extensions suggest that the probability of this occurring is very small...

Comment: ... indeed sufficiently small so that there is a non-zero probability that there are no such extensions for any such $G$, and then $K^S = K$. Of course, we don't even know a single example with $S = \emptyset$ such that $K^S = K$ and the root discriminant of $K$ exceeds the Odlyzko bounds. There are some contexts (e.g. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ant/1510842310) which suggest the heuristics above need to be taken with a grain of salt, but these examples only involve $S$ containing all primes above $2$ and so are somewhat orthogonal to the question you are posing.

Answer (score 1):

@David   Does your question mean (even in vague terms) : "Given $K$, what is the "smallest" $S$ such that $K^S/K$ is infinite ?". Because the examination of miscellaneous known cases seems to suggest the contrary of a uniform answer. Throughout, fix a prime number $p$ (assumed to be odd to avoid petty trouble) and shift the problem from $K^S$ to $K^S (p)$ = the maximal pro-$p$-extension of $K$ unramified outside $S$, with Galois group $ {G^S_K}(p)= Gal(K^S (p)/K)$ .

1) Take $S$ containing all the $p$-places of $K$. It is well known by CFT that ${G^S_K}(p)^{ab}$ is a $\mathbf Z_p$-module of rank $1+r_2+ \delta$, where $r_2$ is the number of complex places of $K$ and $\delta \in \mathbf N$ is conjecturally null. So the point is whether $S$ can be downsized or not.

2) Let us first remove some $p$-places from $S$. Consider an imaginary quadratic field $k$ s.t. $p$ splits completely in $k$, say $(p)=P.P^*$, and an elliptic curve $E$ defined over a number field $F$, with complex multiplication by the ring of integers of $k$. Suppose moreover that $E$ has good ordinary reduction at any $p$-place. Then the field $F(E_{P^{\infty}})$ obtained by adding all the $P^n$-torsion points of $E$ is a $\mathbf Z_p$-extension of $K=F(E_P)$. Thus $K^S/K$ is infinite, with  $S$={$P$}.

3) Let us be go to extremities and cut $S$ down to the empty set, so that $K^S (p)$ is the so-called "$p$-class field tower". The Golod-Safarevic theorem says that there exists a function $\gamma (n)$ s.t., for all number fields $k$ of degree $n$ with finite $p$-class field tower, $\gamma(n)$ > the minimal number of generators of the $p$-class group of $k$. One can even take $\gamma(n)=2+2\sqrt(n+1)$. Moreover, for a finite $p$-group $G$, it is known by cohomological considerations that $r(G) > \frac 14 d(G)^2$ , where $d(G)$ (resp. $r(G)$) dotes the minimal number of generators (resp. relations) of $G$. The combination of these two properties produces examples of finite as well as of infinite $p$-class field towers.

4) Another approach lies in the "tame" situation, in which $S$ contains *no* $p$-place, hence $K^S (p)$ contains no $\mathbf Z_p$-extension, hence ${G^S_K}(p)^{ab}$ is finite (this property is called FAB). At the beginning of this century, somewhat to the general surprise, J. Labute produced a family of Galois groups $G^S_{\mathbf Q}(p)$ called *mild*, of cohomological dimension $2$, hence torsion free, hence infinite. Roughly speaking, the initial terms of the relations of a mild pro-$p$-group $G$ must satisfy special combinatorial properties in order that the graded algebra built on the lower $p$-central series of $G$ has a nice convenient description in terms of the corresponding free graded algebra. Subsequent developments by A. Schmidt *et. al.* provide an infinite supply of examples over arbitrary number fields. One should
also remark the relevance of arithmetical FAB groups with regard to the Fontaine-Mazur conjecture on $p$-adic representations  ./.

Comment: First, $K^S(p)$ is a very different type of extension from $K^S$ and is much more closely related to class
field theory (it also seems to assume that $S$ is a subset of primes dividing some fixed $p$). Second, it seems clear from the original question (and the mention of G-S) that the OP is not expecting a "uniform" answer, just asking if there are any non-trivial general results which guarantee that $K^S$ is infinite.

Comment: @Infinity  I don't understand your comment. If $K^S (p)/K$ is infinite, then so is $K^S/K$. Besides, in the "tame" case, $S$ is coprime to $p$. So I did actually give "non trivial general results" implying the unfiniteness of $K^S/K$.

Comment: What you write is very interesting, but it appears to be aiming at a slightly different question than the one I actually asked! As @infinity points out, it might (potentially) happen that $K^S(p) / K$ might be finite for every $p$, for some fixed $K$ and $S$, but $K^S / K$ infinite.

Comment: Put as this, I agree, although the point did not appear very clearly in your original question. That was why my answer only dealt with examples of infinite $K^S(p)/K$ ($p$ arbitrary).